# Integral of $\int\frac{1}{4x^2+4x+2}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> Solve: $$\int\frac{1}{4x^2+4x+2}dx$$

I think it may related to $\tan^{-1}x$. Any hint?

Comment: Is it $4x^4+4x^2+1$ or $4x^4+4x+1$?

Comment: It is $4x^4+4x+2$

Comment: Wolframalpha doesn't seem to give a nice solution.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If the roots are ugly, then the solution must be ugly as well. There is no going around that.

Comment: I have tried to factorize the denominator and wanted to get closer to the form of $\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The denominator turns into $$(2x+1)^2+1$$

so you can make the substitution $$y = 2x+1$$ to turn the integral into

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{y^2+1}\ dy$$

Then try to make a trigonometric substitution.